# locking and unlocking tables when running minitest

Tags: sql, ruby, minitest

I have been tasked to Lock a Development Database before running a series of minitest test scripts and then unlock the database after all the test has completed.

All the tests are run by executing the Rake file using rake test.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

1. By editing every test scripts' before_suite and after_suite?
2. Is there a setting or some specific code that can be added to Rakefile?
3. Is there a setting or some speficic code that I can add to test_helper.ds?
4. Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think 1. is the way to go. Then in the Rakefile, you can treat every test the same, and if each test is independent or locks the shared resource ( a database in your case), you've got yourself a nicely pararelizable test suite.

Of course, you don't want to be actually copy pasting the locking/unlocking code. I think the way to share the code among your test cases is either by defining a custom module like the documentation recommends (http://docs.seattlerb.org/minitest/) and including that module in the tests that need to lock the database or by making your testcases inherit from a customized class that inherits from Minitest::Test, both of which you can put in your test helper.

**EDIT--In Code:**

```
module LockDb
  #Replace this with the path to your actual database
  DB_FILE = 'db'

  def setup
    @f = File.open(DB_FILE, 'r+')
    @f.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
  end
  def teardown
    @f.flock(File::LOCK_UN)
  end
end
```

You would include this in the test classes that you want to lock the db like so:

```
class TestMeme < Minitest::Test
include LockDb
#Your tests
end
```

To see that it works, you can setup a simple test-frameworkless script like the following, and have fun by running it in multiple windows (make sure to `touch db` before you run it so it can open the file it expects):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

module LockDb
  #Replace this with the path to your actual database
  DB_FILE = 'db'

  def setup
    @f = File.open(DB_FILE, 'r+')
    @f.flock(File::LOCK_EX)
  end
  def teardown
    @f.flock(File::LOCK_UN)
  end
end

extend LockDb

#The setup hook is run before each test method in minitest
setup
puts "Locked"

#This would be one of your test methods
puts "Press Enter to unlock"
gets
#^This would be the end of one of your test methods

#The teardown hook is run before each test method in minitest
teardown
puts "Unlocked"
```

**On the comment:**
If you already have those methods, they will override the ones provided by the module, so you'll need to modify those already defined methods to call `super`so that the version provided by the module gets called too. (Splitting the module is pointless and logically, you'll always need to call the whole pair)

If that seems like too much work, you can also try the to take the rake route, e.g.,

```
namespace :old do
   #put the old :test definition here
end

task :teardown => 'old:test' do
   #the code
end
task 'old:test' => :setup
task :setup  do
   #the code

end
task :test => :teardown
```

Or you can use https://github.com/guillermo/rake-hooks .

Comment: Yes, I realized that so I deleted the comment.  I don't control over what gems can be installed. I'll let you know how I finally resolved it. Thanks for all the help. I'd like to mark your answer as correct, but don't see the option.

Comment: The resolution turned out to be much simplier than expected.  In test_helper.ds I added a class that locked the database.  After that class I used Minitest.after_run { }  to unlock the database.   No need for modules or updating existing test classes!